# Accessing Host machine urls from Ubuntu VM

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have an Ubuntu VM on my windows host machine. I have installed Hashicorp consul on my windows host machine. I am trying to run docker container and trying to access the consul url from the VM using ip. But I am unable to do so. 
Is there a way where I can access any host machine url from the ubuntu virtual machine. I am not able to access any url of app deployed on host machine from vm.

Comment: What network type did you assign?

Comment: I used Bridged adapter and also NAT network settings in ubuntu